# Justifying term by term differentiation of spherical harmonics expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives, spherical-harmonics

I saw in many physics texts term by term differentiation of spherical harmonics expansion, but since they're physics texts they're without rigourous proof. Take for example the following from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics)

> Given the multipole expansion of a scalar field
>
> ${\displaystyle \phi =\sum _{\ell =0}^{\infty }\sum _{m=-\ell }^{\ell
>  }\phi _{\ell m}(r)Y_{\ell m}(\theta ,\phi ),}$
>
> we can express its gradient in terms of the VSH as
>
> ${\displaystyle \nabla \phi =\sum _{\ell =0}^{\infty }\sum _{m=-\ell
>  }^{\ell }\left({\frac {d\phi _{\ell m}}{dr}}\mathbf {Y} _{\ell
>  m}+{\frac {\phi _{\ell m}}{r}}\mathbf {\Psi } _{\ell m}\right).}$

I know the spherical harmonics $Y_{\ell m}$ forms an orthonormal basis for $L^2$ functions, so that any $L^2$ function $\phi$ can be written as an infinite series expansion of spherical harmonics in the above way. If $\phi$ is $H^1$ function, then we expect its derivative to also have an spherical harmonic expansion. However, how do we know rigourosuly that it can be obtained by term by term differentiation of the series for $\phi$ in the above manner? In other words, how do we know the coefficients for the spherical harmonic expansion of $\nabla\phi$ is related to the coefficients for the spherical harmonic expansion of $\phi$ via term by term differentiation? Since the convergence of the series that I know of is only in $L^2$, not uniform, I can't quite see how to properly justify it.. Could one justify it if we have more regularity like $C^k$ for some large $k$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4668839/307971. The situation is slightly different here, though, because of the r-dependence.

Answer (score 1):

The sad truth is that this will not be true in general.  However, there is a magic wand, called distribution theory.  Your series converges in the distributional sense and there we have the freshman‘s dream come true— convergence is preserved under differentiation.  This is shown in any standard text (fortunately, there are elementary approaches which avoid the use of functional analysis, in particular, duality theory for locally convex spaces).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "convergence is preserved under differentiation" on distributional sense? Also, you say "this will not be true in general", how about if my functions are C^k for some k allowed to be very large? Thanks

Comment: About the second point, I don‘t think you are understanding the phrase „not in general“ correctly.  As for the first one, if a sequence converges in the distributional sense (and, in particular, in $L^2$), then so does the sequence of its derivatives.  This means that you can always obtain correct formulae by differentiating term by term the kind of series developments you are talking about.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. But I need to fit boundary conditions on my function, which means I need the formula to hold on a zero measure set, say the boundary of the ball $B_1$. So I think it's not enough to just have convergence in the distributional sense. But I'm allowed to assume $C^k$ smoothness for any $k$